# After connecting EOS RP to computer, the lamp blinks green and camera doesn't work

Tags: canon, usb

I connected my EOS RP to a computer via:

- a laptop dock,
- an unpowered USB-C to 4x USB-A hub,
- a USB-A to USB-C cable.

The camera was set to "off". The camera started to blink its LED green, and it doesn't work anymore, even after I unplugged the cable! The camera was not visible to the computer with the cable attached and power switch in "on" state, and when the cable is disconnected, it won't turn on anymore, so I can't take pictures. What's the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the manual, a blinking green LED means charging failure.
Apparently, the camera for some reason thought it could charge itself via the
USB hub which can't supply enough power for charging.

To resolve the issue, the manual recommends unplugging the cable and 
reattaching the battery. Actually, to me, the solution was just to open the
battery door: apparently, the camera has a sensor for the battery door and if
it's opened it automatically resets itself.

The camera is not broken. A blinking green LED problem can be solved by just
opening the battery door.

The issue was probably some transient flaw, as subsequent trials resulted in a
working connection between the camera and the computer.

If the issue persists, one way to improve the connection is to turn on the
camera first and only then connect the cable. This way, the camera shouldn't
even attempt USB charging (which requires camera power to be off).

Another improvement is to use a USB port supporting USB power delivery, if any 
(without any hubs inbetween). Then charging should also work.